# Correct usage of C++ STL set_symmetric_difference?

Tags: c++, stl, set

In C++ I want to take two STL sets and produce a set which contains all the elements that are not in both sets, using `set_symmetric_difference` in `algorithm`.

I am getting a compile error "'_UDest': you cannot assign to a variable that is const", so I am misunderstanding how to use `set_symmetric_difference`.

Here is the code (C++ compiler is Visual Studio 2019):

```
set<unsigned short> a, b, diff;
// code to add entries to a and b
set_symmetric_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), diff.begin()); // error C3892: '_UDest': you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

Comment: You can't insert using `diff.begin()`. Check out [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter).

Comment: You can't write to a sorted container like you do to a vector or deque. They are totally different beasts. You seem to lack the basics: get a good teaching book. You can't learn C++ by trials and errors!

Comment: @curiousguy: That wouldn't work right if `diff` were a `vector` or `deque` either. You'd need to either size it sufficiently or use `std::back_inserter` for a sequence container.

Comment: @FredLarson That wouldn't work w/ regular vector iterators and as a bonus you get no compile time error, only a memory corruption!

Answer (score 3):

You're passing an iterator into the empty set `diff`, as your "output iterator". Iterators don't work like this. `diff.begin()` refers to *existing* elements (of which there are none).

Set elements are immutable (they have to be, in order to maintain their ordering invariant), and that's why the *particular* error message you get relates to `const`ness. However, without this factor, you'd still be trying to write into elements that don't exist.

**You can instead use the special [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) magic iterator to wrap insertions into `diff`**, like in [the `set_symmetric_difference` usage example on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) (though that one uses sorted `std::vector` "sets" rather than `std::set`, so it gets to use `std::back_inserter`).

Here's an example:

```
std::set<unsigned short> a, b, diff;
// (code to add entries to a and b)

std::set_symmetric_difference(
   a.begin(), a.end(),
   b.begin(), b.end(),
   std::inserter(diff, diff.begin())  // <---
);
```

You'll need `#include <iterator>` for this.